# Pandas: Merge datasets of different frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I have both monthly and bi-annual data, which I want to join.

Monthly:

```
                           foo        foobar
date       INCAGG                           
2003-01-01 1          7.892858  7.623477e+07
           3        123.995220  2.120104e+08
           5        133.645028  3.124879e+08
           7        792.390234  5.401223e+08
2003-02-01 1        175.326590  7.037367e+07
           3        295.189979  3.515387e+08
           5        704.893690  3.301345e+08
           7        174.118220  6.025263e+08
2003-03-01 1       2068.875565  6.646029e+07
           3        213.663057  1.821990e+08
           5       2507.293175  2.017673e+08
           7        433.253711  4.542890e+08
2003-04-01 1         79.069296  3.253000e+07
           3         38.485372  5.502446e+07
           5        170.548422  6.304233e+08
           7       1363.115717  4.413133e+08
```

Bi-Annual:

```
                     foobar
date       INCAGG          
2003-01-01 1       0.113312
           3       0.167293
           5       0.283961
           7       0.346094
           9       0.089340
2005-01-01 1       0.119631
           3       0.155010
           5       0.301366
           7       0.332117
           9       0.091877
```

A straight join would match these only for the firsts of Januarys - what is the proper way to join these?

Comment: What is your expected output ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to happen for years that don't get a biannual measurement?  Last available or none?

```
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)

merged = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on=[df1.date.dt.year,'INCAGG'],
        right_on=[df2.date.dt.year,'INCAGG'],suffixes=['','R'],
        how='left').set_index(['date','INCAGG'])

del merged['dateR']
```

Output:

```
                           foo        foobar   foobarR
date       INCAGG                                     
2003-01-01 1          7.892858  7.623477e+07  0.113312
           3        123.995220  2.120104e+08  0.167293
           5        133.645028  3.124879e+08  0.283961
           7        792.390234  5.401223e+08  0.346094
2003-02-01 1        175.326590  7.037367e+07  0.113312
           3        295.189979  3.515387e+08  0.167293
           5        704.893690  3.301345e+08  0.283961
           7        174.118220  6.025263e+08  0.346094
2003-03-01 1       2068.875565  6.646029e+07  0.113312
           3        213.663057  1.821990e+08  0.167293
           5       2507.293175  2.017673e+08  0.283961
           7        433.253711  4.542890e+08  0.346094
2003-04-01 1         79.069296  3.253000e+07  0.113312
           3         38.485372  5.502446e+07  0.167293
           5        170.548422  6.304233e+08  0.283961
           7       1363.115717  4.413133e+00  0.346094
```